# Is there any way to get the sql of a view just by passing the name of the view in Google bigquery?

Tags: python, google-cloud-datastore, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to write a python script which pulls all the views in a dataset .
Is there any way to get the sql of a view just by passing the name of the view in Google bigquery ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the [tables.get method](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables/get) on the view, and examine the [view.query attribute](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables).

(You can't get the view's SQL text via the query interface, if that's what you're asking.)